# Groupby count, average, Q1, Q2, Q3 and standard deviation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID     Sector    Year            Usage   Rent       
1      SE1       2017            R       100            
2      SE1       2017            C       120            
3      SE1       2017            R       150            
4      SE1       2017            R       110            
5      SE1       2017            C       200            
6      SE1       2018            R       100            
7      SE1       2018            R       120            
8      SE1       2018            R       100            
9      SE1       2018            C       100            
10     SE1       2018            C       100  
1      SE2       2017            R       100            
2      SE2       2017            C       120            
3      SE2       2017            R       150            
4      SE2       2017            R       110            
5      SE2       2017            C       200            
6      SE2       2018            R       100            
7      SE2       2018            R       120            
8      SE2       2018            R       100            
9      SE2       2018            C       100            
10     SE2       2018            C       100 
11     SE2       2018            C       100
```

From the above data frame I would like prepare below data frame

Expected Output

```
Sector     Year     Usage     N_of_contract      Mean_Rent    Q1   Q2   Q3   Std
SE1        2017     R         3
SE1        2017     C         2
SE1        2018     R
SE1        2018     C
SE2        2017     R         
SE2        2017     C         
SE2        2018     R
SE2        2018     C
```

Where N_of_contract = Number of times such combination happened, just the count

Mean_Rent = Mean rent of such combination

Q1 = Q1 Rent and so on

Std = Standard deviation of the rent.

NOTE: values of the some columns I am not writing because I am not able to calculate that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html) with [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
new_df = (df.groupby(['Sector','Year','Usage'])['Rent']
            .describe()
            .drop(columns = ['min','max'])
            .reset_index()
            )
print(new_df)
  Sector  Year Usage  count        mean        std    25%    50%    75%
0    SE1  2017     C    2.0  160.000000  56.568542  140.0  160.0  180.0
1    SE1  2017     R    3.0  120.000000  26.457513  105.0  110.0  130.0
2    SE1  2018     C    2.0  100.000000   0.000000  100.0  100.0  100.0
3    SE1  2018     R    3.0  106.666667  11.547005  100.0  100.0  110.0
4    SE2  2017     C    2.0  160.000000  56.568542  140.0  160.0  180.0
5    SE2  2017     R    3.0  120.000000  26.457513  105.0  110.0  130.0
6    SE2  2018     C    3.0  100.000000   0.000000  100.0  100.0  100.0
7    SE2  2018     R    3.0  106.666667  11.547005  100.0  100.0  110.0
```